# Rails 4 - How can I show all nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I'm new in Rails, I do a model with nested attributes, works perfectly. But in the time to show all nested attributes, I get an error.

Model

```
class Slide < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:img_str].blank? }
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :slide
    validates :img_str, presence: true
    mount_uploader :img_str, AssetUploader
end
```

slides_controller

```
def index
    @slide = Slide.all
end
```

slide/view/index

```
<% @slide.each do |slide| %>
  <%= slide.images.img_str %>
<% end %>
```

Rails show this:

```
undefined method `img_str' for #Image::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000003e98dd0
```

How I can make the the association with image model?

Comment: You might want to eager load images for slides in `index` method to avoid n+1 queries: `@slide = Slide.includes(:images).all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`images` is a collection of image objects. What you are doing is like calling the attribute of image object on an array of image objects

```
<% @slide.each do |slide| %>
  <%slide.images.each do |image|%>
     <%= image.img_str %>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Actually you don't need `=` in `<%= slide.images.each do |image|%>`, it can be just `<% slide.images.each do |image| %>`.